# Downloading files from Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, download, paperclip

I have a controller action that is meant to send a file to the user for download from my bucket in S3.

Here's the controller code:

```
send_file @project.file.url, :type => @project.file_content_type
```

Here's the error:

```
Cannot read file http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/projects/1/project.xlsx?2011
```

When I go to the URL directly, I get a download of the file! What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it ok if you just redirect the user to the file on S3?

```
redirect_to @project.file.url
```

The issue is that `send_file` expects a path to a local file, which is then used by the webserver to serve up data from the local file it can access on disk. The file on S3 is only accessible by HTTP, so your webserver can't serve it. To use `send_file` you'd have to download it and then serve it I think.

Comment: @homairs - what do you mean it expects a 'file'? Would it not recognize something as simple as a .pdf or .xslx as a file?

Comment: @homairs - is there a way I can do that? I asked a related question just now regarding how to tell when the download is complete. I imagine I can only do that by keeping the download 'within' my server, rather than doing a redirect_to s3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787625/